# How to delete a Pool user in AWS Cognito and C#?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have used the aws-samples example named aws-cognito-dot-net-desktop-app in C# and Android:

[aws-cognito-dot-net-desktop-app](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cognito-dot-net-desktop-app)

It works very well and correctly registers the user in Cognito.

To register a user, do the following:

```c
bool success = await helper.SignUpUser(etUserName.Text, etPasswordUser.Text, etEmailUser.Text, etPhoneUser.Text);
```

That way the user is created, but a code needs to be entered that is sent to the user's email. The code entry is as follows:

```c
CognitoHelper cognitoHelper = new CognitoHelper();
return await cognitoHelper.VerifyAccessCode(userName, codeSentToMail);
```

and the user registers without problems, that is to say, it works correctly:

[image: user register ok]

Now I want to delete any user created, for which I am creating a task as follows:

```c
internal async Task<bool> DeleteUser(string username)
{
   try
   {
      AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider =
        new Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new Amazon.Runtime.AnonymousAWSCredentials(), RegionEndpoint.USEast1);            

      DeleteUserPoolRequest request = new DeleteUserPoolRequest();
      request.UserPoolId = username;
      DeleteUserPoolResponse deleteUserPoolClientResponse = await provider.DeleteUserPoolAsync(request);
      return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(ex);
       return false;
    }
}
```

When executing DeleteUserPoolRequest, an exception is thrown indicating an error of type Amazon.Runtime.ErrorType.Unknown

[image: Error Amazon]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static async Task<bool> DeleteUserFromAws(string emailId)
    {
        try
        {
            AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient cognito =
            new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey, Region1);
            CognitoUserPool cognitoUserPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolId, appClienId, cognito);
            AdminGetUserRequest adminGetUserRequest = new AdminGetUserRequest();
            adminGetUserRequest.Username = emailId;
            adminGetUserRequest.UserPoolId = poolId;
            AdminGetUserResponse adminGetUserResponse = await cognito.AdminGetUserAsync(adminGetUserRequest);
            var getUserNameByEmaliID = adminGetUserResponse.Username;
           
            AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider =
              new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey, Region1);
            AdminDeleteUserRequest request = new AdminDeleteUserRequest();
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default;
            request.Username = getUserNameByEmaliID;
            request.UserPoolId = poolId;
            await provider.AdminDeleteUserAsync(request,cancellationToken);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.log(ex, (Int32)Category.Fatal, (Int32)Priority.High);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).